# C# unusual inheritance syntax w/ generics

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, syntax, design-patterns

I happened upon this in an NHibernate class definition:

```
public class SQLiteConfiguration : PersistenceConfiguration<SQLiteConfiguration>
```

So this class inherits from a base class that is parameterized by... the derived class?   My head just exploded.

Can someone explain what this means and how this pattern is useful?

(This is NOT an NHibernate-specific question, by the way.)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783321/why-does-this-generic-constraint-compile-when-it-seems-to-have-a-circular-referen/3789193#3789193

Comment: Eric:  I had cited this SO question below in my comments to Lambert.

Comment: I read this thread quite a while ago but only now came across this specific scenario. I found the thread again by searching for "my head just exploded". LOL. Good thing you wrote that or I may never have found it again. :-)

Comment: "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern" is such a boring name.  I hereby re-christen this pattern as the "Cranial Rupture Template Pattern."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[That's a funny Curiously Recurring Template Pattern, isn't it?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: Huh.  I never, ever thought I would find myself laughing out loud at inheritance syntax.  Here's another SO question that is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327568/curiously-recurring-template-pattern-and-generics-constraints-c

Comment: Here's another great discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783321/why-does-this-generic-constraint-compile-when-it-seems-to-have-a-circular-referen.  Also: http://fernandof.wordpress.com/2007/09/23/recursive-generics-restrictions/

Answer (score 2):

I have used the same pattern when developing a double linked tree. Each node has 1 parent, and 0-many children

```
class Tree<T> where T : Tree<T>
{
    T parent;
    List<T> children;
    T Parent { get; set; }
    protected Tree(T parent) 
    {
        this.parent = parent; 
        parent.children.Add(this);
    }
    // lots more code handling tree list stuff
}
```

implementation

```
class Coordinate : Tree<Coordinate>
{
    Coordinate(Coordinate parent) : this(parent) { }
    static readonly Coordinate Root = new Coordinate(null);
    // lots more code handling coordinate systems
}
```

usage

```
Coordinate A = Coordinate.Root;
Coordinate B = new Coordinate(A);

B.Parent // returns a Coordinate type instead of a Node<>.
```

So anything that inherits from `Tree<>` will contain properties for parent and children objects in the appropriate type. This trick is pure *magic* for me.

Comment: Thank you, jalexiou, for the very specific response!  I have to admit that it will take me a while to understand this.

Comment: @anon - Try it! Fire up old C# development and code something up like this.

Comment: @anon - Of course, it is missing constructors, property accessors and many more. It is just skeleton code.